# Writing and reading an array with specified keys to a json file

Tags: php, arrays, json, file

I have an array

```
$monthlyStatistics = array('total' => 1, 'opened' => 1, 'clicked' => 1, 'bounced' => 1, 'optout' => 1);
```

that I have saved to a json file

```
$monthlypath = '/storage/monthlytotals.json';
file_put_contents($monthlypath, json_encode($monthlyStatistics));
```

and I need to read this json file and output the contents as an array with the specified keys. I am currently doing this:

```
$monthlypath = '/storage/monthlytotals.json';
$read_file = file_get_contents($monthlypath);
$monthlytotals = json_decode($read_file);
```

which I know that file_put_contents puts as a string and that file() is supposed to read the entire file into an array (which I am currently not using since it doesn't read what file_put_contents wrote).

Am I doing this wrong or am I missing a function that is supposed to go along with file() for writing it properly as an array?

Comment: Have you read the documentation of [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)?

Comment: Yes I have read the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to convert from a PHP data structure in memory to something that can be written to disk. Somehow that needs serialising - either through `json_encode()` or `serialize()` etc.

`file()` reads a file into a list of lines (one line per array entry).

For what you're doing,

`file_put_contents($monthlypath, json_encode($totals))`

and

`$totals = json_decode(file_get_contents($monthlypath), true)`

are probably all you probably need.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that and get back to you. Will that suggested method keep the specified key values?

Comment: Yes. Both will.
 'serialize' will handle more php data types (specifically objects), while 'json_encode' is probably safer.